# SQL Constraint delete doesn't remove child but gives a error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

*2 Tables:*

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
    ID     int PRIMARY KEY,
    name   varchar2(50) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE length (
    ID        int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES movie(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    length    int NOT NULL
);
```

So I tried to delete values from both by:

```
delete from movie where ID=1;
```

but get the error:

```
"attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign dependency."
```

Why if I use ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: What DBMS are you actually using? varchar2 is NOT a valid sql server datatype. Is this Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, Yes this is Oracle (SQL Developer)

Comment: The `CASCADE` option works on the other direction. If you delete from length, it will delete referencing rows on child table. Check the relationship definition.

Comment: @Alfabravo sure, but movie is the parent and length the child...

Comment: Exactly that's why you'd check @Lorena's answer

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in your relationship. It seems to be a "one to many" relationship, and the FK is in the `lenght` table which means that a movie has many lengths. Is it that what you meant?

Usually, `length` can be placed as a attribute of table `movie`. But if you want to keep this attribute as a separated table, I would suggest you to create a FK, in your table movie, that references the table `length`.

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
    ID     int PRIMARY KEY,
    name   varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_length
    FOREIGN KEY (id_length)
    REFERENCES length(ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE length (
    ID        int PRIMARY KEY,
    length    int NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this using the tables you've given in your question.  Here's a session in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE movie (
  2      ID     int PRIMARY KEY,
  3      name   varchar2(50) NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE length (
  2      ID        int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES movie(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  3      length    int NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into movie (id, name) values (1, 'Test');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into length (id, length) values (1, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> delete from movie where id=1;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * from length;

no rows selected
```

I suspect that the foreign key constraint on your `length` table doesn't have the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause you think it does.  Perhaps you created this table previously without this clause, and when you tried to create this table again with `ON DELETE CASCADE` you didn't notice SQL Developer failing to create the table? (Creating the table the second time would fail because the table already existed.)

Try dropping the `length` table and creating it again.